# In complex analytic category, is the pluricanonical sheaf Cohen--Macaulay?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

We adopt the following definition of canonical singularities in complex analytic category.
Let $X$ be a normal complex space of dimension $n$, and let $j:X_{\text{reg}}\rightarrow X$ be the open immersion of the smooth locus. We define the $\textit{canonical sheaf}$ as $\omega_X=j_{*}K_{X_{\text{reg}}}$ with the canonical bundle $K_{X_\text{reg}}$ of $X_\text{reg}$, and the $\textit{$r$-canonical sheaf}$ by $\omega_X^{[r]}=j_*(K^{\otimes r}_{X_{\text{reg}}})$ for every positive integer. This is a reflexive sheaf of rank one on $X$ satisfying $\omega_X^{[r]}=(\omega_X^{\otimes r})^{**}$, where $(\,\,)^{**}$ means the double dual.
We say $X$ possesses at most $\textit{canonical singularities}$ if the following two conditions hold:

1. $X$ is $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein, i.e., there exists some positive integer $r$, such that
   the $r$-canonical sheaf is locally free. We call the minimum of such $r$ the $\textit{index}$  of $X$ and call $X$ $r$-Gorenstein.
2. For some (or any, equivalently) resolution $\mu:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ of $r$-Gorenstein space $X$, the pull back of the generator $\beta$ of $\omega_X^{[r]}$ is holomorphic, i.e., $\mu^*\beta\in H^0(\widetilde{X}, K^{\otimes r}_{\widetilde{X}})$.

In algebraic complex category, since we always have the canonical divisor $K_X$, the following seems to be well-known to experts. Notice that in contrast, in a normal complex space or even complex manifold, we cannot associated some divisor to a reflexive sheaf of rank one. Some space (or, manifold) even doesn't have any divisors!

> Let $X$ be a normal complex (algebraic) variety with only canonical singularities, then $\mathcal O_X(mK_X)$ is Cohen-Macaulay for any integer $m$.

I am interested in the analytic category, so here is my question:
Let $X$ be a normal complex space with only canonical singularities, is any pluri-canonical sheaf  $\omega_X^{[r]}$ Cohen-Macaulay for any integer $m$?

Any references and suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.